# How can I protect an accessor only IEnumerable<string> property from mutation?

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

Suppose I have this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly List<string> _strings = new List<string>();

    public IEnumerable<string> MyStrings 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _strings; 
        }
    }
}
```

How can I prevent the following from actually adding to the member variable list of string?

```
var theClass = new MyClass();
((List<string>)theClass.MyStrings).Add("I do not want to be able to add this!");
```

Comment: Is there a difference between `MyStrings` and `AllStrings`?

Comment: What about IReadOnlyCollection<T> ?

Comment: @JLevett: What would that change? The "read-only" collection could still be treated with typecasting to retrieve the writeable list.

Comment: @p.s.w.g - oops, I had originally called the property `AllStrings` and then changed it `MyStrings`, updated question.

Comment: The ToList() suggestion is simple and protects the *collection* from mutation, but its *elements* are naked to the sky. People who want to live in a cotton-wool world must do a deep copy of every element. This of course is absurd, and since half a seat-belt provides only the delusion of safety, it's better to say "You're big boys and your toys are dangerous, if you like your fingers then have some care and keep a tidy workshop." Servy's suggestion of generating a new enumerable using LINQ has the advantage that it can also do the deep copies for you, in the select clause.

Comment: @PeterWone The items in the collections are strings, which are immutable, so no, he doesn't need to do anything else.

Comment: @Servy - sure. Mine is more general pontification, because the cotton-wool-worlders would take away my knives and chisels, and then wonder why nothing got done. Real Programmers can write FORTRAN in any language...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a new type that "wraps" the sequence.  While there are many ways of doing this, one fairly simple "hack" is to just use `Select` on it with the identity transformation:

```
return _strings.Select(x=>x);
```

This will create a new object with it's own iterator that, internally, has a reference to the `_strings` list.  Due to that extra layer of indirection (and with the extra bonus of the type being a type internal to the language that is not valid to use outside of the language definition), the caller can no longer cast their way to the list.

If you want something that's a bit clearer to read that makes the intentions a bit more known, you can just make a new method for it:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AsSequence<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    return sequence.Select(x => x);
}
```

(Feel free to name it whatever is clearest to you.)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how you plan to use this property, you could try one of these:

```
public IEnumerable<string> MyStrings
{ 
    get 
    { 
        foreach (var s in _strings)
            yield return s; 
    }
}
```

or

```
public IEnumerator<string> MyStringsEnumerator
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return _strings.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Both are returning an enumerator over the list, so the list can't be altered by users of those properties.

The first one creates a new iterator by using the `yield` keyword. It is convenient for users of `MyStrings`, as it returns an `IEnumerable<string>`, so LINQ can be used on it.

The second one returns the built-in `List<T>` enumerator. It returns an `IEnumerator<string>`, so is less convenient to use.

Make sure to read docs at MSDN if this code will be used in a multithread application, or if code using this property is outside of your control - especially note how the existing iterators are invalidated and have undefined behavior when the underlying collection is altered.

Answer (score 2):

There is a common approach to expose [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
private readonly List<string> _strings = new List<string>();

public IEnumerable<string> MyStrings 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(_strings);
    }
}
```

If you try to invoke the following code you'll get an exception.

```
var theClass = new MyClass();
((List<string>)theClass.MyStrings).Add("I do not want to be able to add this!");
```

Comment: + `return` ... or store the `ReadOnlyCollection` in an additional private field if the property is going to be accessed very frequently.

Comment: When using ReadOnlyCollection, you can change the return type to `IReadOnlyCollection` to indicate that its safe to enumerate the list more than once (and that .Count is constant speed)

Comment: @O. R. Mapper It is OK when you do not need to edit your backing collection at all.

Comment: @IlyaPalkin: `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` is only a wrapper around the backing collection, so any changes to the backing collection will be visible via the wrapping `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, no matter when the latter was created.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still needs help with this and is using .net "core" i recommend ImmutableList.

```
private ImmutableList<String> _MyStrings = ImmutableList<String>.Empty;

public IEnumerable<String> MyStrings => this._MyStrings;
```

Answer (score -1):

Return a copy of the collection. Then it doesn't matter if the consumer of your class does add to it, and it doesn't matter if you mess with your copy of the list either.

```
private readonly List<string> _strings = new List<string>();

public IEnumerable<string> MyStrings 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return new List<string>(_strings);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) this doesn't get deferred execution; if the underlying list is modified the sequence exposed externally doesn't reflect that 2) There is a very steep performance cost in doing this, especially with respect to memory.

Comment: 1) - Yes, agreed that's entirely my point. It makes a copy when the MyStrings property is accessed, and doesn't change. Every other access to the property returns a snapshot at that point. In some situations I think that's useful. I don't think it's a good idea to advocate changing the collection as it's being enumerated.
2) Please qualify "very steep". It's a trade off, if you like the semantics of returning a copy, then you have to pay for some memory. And the copied list of references automatically gets collected after the enumeration is used.

Comment: The OP clearly *isn't* looking for copy semantics though; he just wants to be able to return an actual reference that simply can't be cast back to the actual list.  The idea is not to mutate the list *during enumeration*, and see it reflected, the idea is that when you enumerate the sequence you see mutations that took place between when you asked for the variable and when you started enumeration.  If the caller wants a snapshot, they can copy the list themselves.